# Algorithm to determine whether a system of multivariate polynomials has a real solution

Tags: algebraic-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry

Say I have a system of multivariate polynomials,
$[P_{1}, ... ,P_{n}]$.
I'm interested in determining whether it has a real-valued solution, but don't necessarily want to find any solutions, or enumerate solutions. I expect that often I'll be dealing with systems that have infinitely many real solutions.

In an algebraically closed field, this can be answered by taking a reduced Groebner basis of $\langle P_{1}, ... P_{n} \rangle$. If I'm not mistaken, the system has no solutions iff its reduced Groebner basis is {1}.

Is there an analogous algorithm for determining whether there are real solutions to a system? If not, what algorithms are available?

Comment: See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66857/existence-of-a-real-valued-solution-to-system-of-multivariate-polynomial-equatio) on MO.